# Change storage folder on file upload

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have form with fields like

'name, firstname, street, zip, city and image'.

The image was an upload 
field. Everything works fine, i can upload the image as Filereferrence. But the image was uploaded every time into `"fileadmin/"`. I want to upload the image into `"/uploads/<extensionname>"` or `"fileadmin/user_uploads/<extensionname>"`.

The part where the upload and file moving was realized look like.

```
            $storageRepository = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Resource\\StorageRepository');

            $storage = $storageRepository->findByUid('1');

            $fileData = array();
            $fileData['name'] = $_FILES['tx_oaevents_eventslisting']['name']['image'][0];
            $fileData['type'] = $_FILES['tx_oaevents_eventslisting']['type']['image'][0];
            $fileData['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['tx_oaevents_eventslisting']['tmp_name']['image'][0];
            $fileData['size'] = $_FILES['tx_oaevents_eventslisting']['size']['image'][0];


            $newFileObject = $storage->addFile(
                $fileData['tmp_name'], $storage->getRootLevelFolder(), $fileData['name']
            );
```

This line deines the storage folder form database:

```
$storage = $storageRepository->findByUid('1');
```

which is fileadmin as default. But what is the best way to change/modify this storage folder destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify the destination folder for your upload, I suggest you take a look at the [FAL File Upload example](https://github.com/helhum/upload_example/blob/master/Classes/Controller/ExampleController.php#L156) from Helmut Hummel. For his example, there is also a [blogpost](http://insight.helhum.io/post/85015526410/file-upload-using-extbase-and-fal-in-typo3-62) which describes how the file upload works and why you should use a TypeConverter for FAL file upload in TYPO3 6.2+

I have implemented the solution several times and it works just great, since it covers a lot of scenarios you may run into when implementing a file upload (e.g. validation, error handling, file replacement if file exists)